# How do I add an image that has been uploaded via JS to the form it is being uploaded from?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-5

I know the title is a bit funky, but what I am trying to do is this.

I have a form, and on the `type=file` field, I am executing a `.fileupload` using jquery-fileupload.

So the upload process works well, but the issue I am facing is, once the upload is finished...basically I want it to be attached to this HTML field:

```
<input class="col-lg-4 form-control" type="file" name="profile[avatar]" id="profile_avatar">
```

This is my JS (truncated for brevity):

```
$("[type=file]").fileupload({
done: function(e, data) {    
        data.progressBar.remove();

        var image = {
          id: data.formData.key.match(/cache\/(.+)/)[1],
          storage: 'cache',
          metadata: {
            size: data.files[0].size,
            filename: data.files[0].name.match(/[^\/\\]+$/)[0],
            mime_type: data.files[0].type
          }
        }

        $('<img src="' + image.metadata.filename + '">').insertAfter($(this))    
      }
  });
```

That produces the following HTML after this operation:

```
<input class="col-lg-4 form-control" type="file" name="profile[avatar]" id="profile_avatar">
<img src="Awesome-Image-1.jpg">
```

That then produces the following error in my console:

```
Awesome-Image-1.jpg:1 GET http://localhost:3000/profiles/Awesome-Image-1.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

So basically I want to take that `image` object that is stored in the `cache` and display it right above the `input` field -- so the user can see the image they uploaded. I don't want to remove the `input` field altogether.

**Edit 1**

So just to be clear, I am not trying to access the image that has been uploaded to the server. I am trying to access the image that is the object within `var image`.

This is the JS Object for the local variable `image`, as accessed in the console:

```
Object {id: "8b455ab4155a6bd0e16e4f4c62165b4b.jpg", storage: "cache", metadata: Object}
```

Here is the full object:

```
Objectid: "8b455ab4155a6bd0e16e4f4c62165b4b.jpg"metadata: Objectfilename: "Awesome-Image-1.jpg"mime_type: "image/jpeg"size: 65715__proto__: Object__defineGetter__: __defineGetter__()__defineSetter__: __defineSetter__()__lookupGetter__: __lookupGetter__()__lookupSetter__: __lookupSetter__()constructor: Object()hasOwnProperty: hasOwnProperty()isPrototypeOf: isPrototypeOf()propertyIsEnumerable: propertyIsEnumerable()toLocaleString: toLocaleString()toString: toString()valueOf: valueOf()get __proto__: __proto__()set __proto__: __proto__()storage: "cache"__proto__: Object__defineGetter__: __defineGetter__()__defineSetter__: __defineSetter__()__lookupGetter__: __lookupGetter__()__lookupSetter__: __lookupSetter__()constructor: Object()hasOwnProperty: hasOwnProperty()isPrototypeOf: isPrototypeOf()propertyIsEnumerable: propertyIsEnumerable()toLocaleString: toLocaleString()toString: toString()valueOf: valueOf()get __proto__: __proto__()set __proto__: __proto__()
```

So how do I take that `image` object, and put it within the form in an `<img>` tag so that it shows that image that is stored in cache?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation for the `.fileupload()` plugin?

Comment: You are viewing a page served by a server, right? You can't display a local image on a remotely served page - browsers don't allow that - neither do you want that - you want assurance that the image has been uploaded and stored in the proper place. So the `<img>` element's `src` attribure needs be the URL of the *uploaded* image. I can't see anywhere in the code that the server informs the client of the image's URL.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Here is the plugin - https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload -- re: the rest of your comment, I am going to update the question with more details.

Comment: What makes you think the image is cached, and what makes you think it can be read directly from cache? Have you read this somewhere? If so, where?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Html

```
<input class="col-lg-4 form-control" type="file" name="profile[avatar]" id="tile-image">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="">
```

Javascript

```
function readURL(input) {
                if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        $('.img-thumbnail').attr('src', e.target.result);
                    }

                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                }
            }
```

on change of file input

```
    $("#tile-image").change(function () {
                readURL(this);
               //your upload code here
            });
```

Comment: How does this relate to my code I entered in my question? Note that I don't need for my HTML to be rendered the way it is in my question. I just want it to work the way I want (with the image above my `input` field). This response seems to stick with my implementation, which may not be the best approach.

Comment: as per my understanding you would like to show the image you are uploading before uploading. right?The above code will show the image you are goint to upload before you upload

Comment: @marcamillion let me try one more time

Comment: I have successfully uploaded a file with my code and it is stored in my local variable `image`. What I want to do is take `image` and plop it onto my form and render it as an image. Ignore the upload part, because I have that taken care of.

Comment: you get faster performance and less code if you use `URL.createObjectURL` instead of using the FileReader: https://jsfiddle.net/fdzmd4mg/1